# Searching a tuple element in a list of lists without changing the data structure

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to search user input in a tuple located in a list of lists.

```
data = [[('tick1',12),4],[('tick2', 16),7],...]

if user input: 'tick1'
desired output:[('tick1',12),4]
```

I can do this if I change my list to a dictionary:

```
data = [[('tick1',12),4],[('tick2', 16),7]]

data = dict(data)

if not any('tick2' in x for x in data):
    print('not found')
else:
    print('found:', x)

#Output
found: [('tick2', 16), 7]
```

But how can I do this if I want to maintain the list type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to iterate over the sublists and check for the user input in `x[0]` which is a tuple

```
data = [[('tick1',12),4],[('tick2', 16),7]]

user_input = 'tick1'

output = [x for x in data if user_input in x[0]]
# [[('tick1', 12), 4]]
```

Comment: @iamchoosinganame: It works for me. Please try it out and let me know the draw back

Comment: @iamchoosinganame, no, because `x[0]` is a tuple

Comment: @iamchoosinganame : No it doesn't. Replace `tick2` by `tick12` and see

Comment: I edited my original comment to mention that I was wrong about this.

Answer (score 3):

You just iterate over all the elements of the list:

```
for (name, num), other in data:
    if name == user_input:
        print("Found it!")
```

Or, if you're into comprehensions:

```
if any(True for (name, num), other in data if name == user_input):
# Or: if any(name == user_input for (name, num), other in data):
    print("Found it!")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for tick in data:
    if tick[0][0]==user_input:
        print(tick)
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the next() function to get the first match and use its default parameter for the case where the item is not in the list:

```
data = [[('tick1',12),4],[('tick2', 16),7]]
result = next( (item for item in data if item[0][0] == 'tick1'), "not found")
print(result) # [('tick1', 12), 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [[('tick1',12),4],[('tick2', 16),7]] # user stored dat
userinput = input() # user giving input

def fun(userinput, data): # a function taking 2 argument, data, userinput
    for i in data: # iterate over each element inside data
        if i[0][0]==userinput: # check if value at position [0][0] is equal to user input
            return i # if equal return that value
    return 'not found' # if no value found equal then return not found

print(fun(userinput, data)) # calling of function and giving input argument , printing the result of return  of the function
```

Comment: comments gone bc explanation added

Answer (score 0):

Collect all list with first item equals input_value. Then check the size if found or not.

```
data = [[('tick1',12),4],[('tick12', 16),7], [('tick1', 11), 4]]
x = 'tick1'
search=[n for n in data for t in n[0] if t==x ]
if len(search) > 0:
    print('found:', search)
else:
    print('not found:', x)

Result: found: [[('tick1', 12), 4], [('tick1', 11), 4]]
```